# Adding Authentication to UWP apps with Azure Mobile App as backend

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, azure-mobile-services

I am working on `UWP` app which requires users to login using social identity providers like `Microsoft`, `Google` etc.
I have followed the quickstart guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users) which describes how the authentication can be added.

In the `UWP` Quickstart app the installed version of `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client` is `3.1.0`, if I upgrade this to the latest version i.e. `4.0.0`, an error is thrown on the line `LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount)` that `LoginAsync` has no overloaded methods that take 1 argument. To resolve this I added a `SingleSignOn` parameter to the method which is a `boolean`

```
var user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount, true);
```

When I run the application the Microsoft login popup is shown successfully, however when the users logs in, the popup does not go away and control never returns to the app. Following is the screenshot:
[image]

If I close the popup manually then an exception is thrown :
`Authentication was cancelled by the user`

So is this a `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client` Nuget package version issue or am I missing something here.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you do not require single sign-on, please try to use ``await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount, false);`` that should work.

Comment: Hi Fred, I tried that but got following exception: `This api is deprecated. Please use LoginSync method with uriScheme parameter.`

Comment: Using Azure Mobile Client SDK v3.1.0, not get this error. But upgrading to v4.0.0, get same error. I am investigating this issue.

Comment: could you check my answer, i think its the right answer to your issue!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll answer to you question now, because I was able to solve it just a couple seconds ago.

So you are using UWP, I'm using Template 10 and I've been able to make it work on both, firstable update to v4.0.0 or v4.0.1 according to what i found out was because google authentication stopped allowing web views for authentication and the concern for Azure-Mobile-Net-Client team was that all OAuth provider would adopt that behavior in the future base on an article that you can find here if you are interested:
[Modernizing OAuth interactions in Native Apps for Better Usability and Security](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html/%22Modernizing%20OAuth%20interactions%20in%20Native%20Apps%20for%20Better%20Usability%20and%20Security%22)

after this being said we are in the middle of a big change here, so in order to make it work you need to set your mobile app service to allow external redirects using url_scheme_of_your_app as shown on microsoft documentations tutorial.

So the step are the next ones:

1.- Go to Azure Portal

2.- Go to your MobileApp Service

3.- Choose Authentication/Authorization

4.- at Allowed External Redirect URLs write this: {urischeme}://easyauth.callback
(meaning that urischeme must be alphanumeric word beginning with a letter).

5.- Save changes.

Now after you have done that now you gotta work on your client
then if you are using UWP follow this tutorial:
[Add Authentication to your UWP.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users#a-nameadd-authenticationaadd-authentication-to-the-app/%22Add%20Authentication%20to%20your%20UWP%22)

and that should be enough, if you are using template 10 all you gotta do is at OnStartAsync Method use this code:

```
 if(startKind == StartKind.Activate)
        {
            ProtocolActivatedEventArgs protocolArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
            cloudService.ResumeWithUrl(protocolArgs.Uri);
        }
```

you saved tons of code at the tutorial because you gotta write code at OnNavigatedTo() Method and at OnActivated() method at App.Xaml.cs

thats for the architecture in UWP and at Template 10 that acts like a wrapper of Application class and simplifies its usage.

Hopefully this helps you, also you will notice that when you first sign in at your app using urischeme it opens your default browser and stays open after successfully logged in.

Also singlesignon overload method doesnt work at all yet, they are still working on those issues.

hopefully my answer helps you!!!

Comment: This is the documentation with Xamarin.Forms buddy, I haven't explore Xamarin Yet, I'm still deeply working with UWP. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users

hope this links help, I think the procedure its the same!!!

Comment: xamarin uwp should 100% the same with uwp itself. so it exposes same apis. only sharing code between android and ios over cross platform library makes difference but in this cause, i dont think that there is difference. my problem here is according to the article  i must end up OnActivated but I never hit it. it show that I am logedin but browser remains and i am not redirect to anywhere. what is OnStartAsync? I cant find this override method. your article is also not active anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add my solution for xamarin.forms on uwp, which should be actually same as we are doing redirecting and login on native level. I followed this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users

but there was something confusing about url scheme of your app part when you define the return url. 
Basically you define return url in 4 places and they sound like the same but they are different

1) you define on facebook developer page. it should (use https) https://myapi.azurewebsites.net//easyauth.callback

2) on the azure portal for allowed external redirect urls
add here 2: https://myapi.azurewebsites.net//easyauth.callback, myapp//easyauth.callback

3) uwp package manifest- declaration. add myapp as name
4) Login call to azure mobile services: Client.LoginAsync(provider, "myapp");

So basically myapp (this is name you choose) should be available in azure portal and same name used in your uwp project. otherwise even login is successful, you end up with this screen instead of redirected back to the app.